# how do you print an image to screen?

Tags: android, image, button

can anyone tell me how to display an image as a thumbnail and when clicked have it appear in a text view of some kind?
Specifically having four image buttons below an output box and when you click one of the 4 images it shows up at the begining of the output box above, the images will also change at that point allowing the user to pick from a set of new images but again clicking one of these adds it to the same output  box next to the last chosen image (creating a kind of picture story or sentence) and I was also looking at adding the sdk text to speech to read back the sentence but I'm not sure where to start all my searches through here and Google have been useless I put it down to me not knowing what I'm looking for please if anyone can point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to display images in a TextView.  However, I did something similar to what you are asking.  See the Perinote app.

My solution was to embed blank spaces at the beginning of the TextView and superimpose the images in onDraw.  Basically, I subclassed TextView, put in some "set" functions to define what images are to be displayed.  As each image is "set", it calcs how many spaces are needed to push the text out of the way.

You can get the width of a space like this:

```
spaceWidth = paint.measureText (" ", 0, 1);
```

The other thing I had to do was to add TextWatcher and block chars from being changed in the preceding space area.  This turned out to be pretty tricky because beforeTextChanged gets called when you insert the "preceding spaces".  You'll need some logic to allow that to happen while blocking other changes to that area.

Comment: Hi don't think this is my answer but mainly cause my question was sooo god aweful thank you soo much for trying to answer it the best you can @Peri Hartman and checked out perinote very clever

Comment: ok, good luck.  If you refine your question, I'll take a look.